# Scifi book dystopian female seer

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

Not sure if it's set in the future but:

- Women live in a large city.
- Men live outside but can visit during the day.
- Marriages are temporary and controlled by the wives.
- One character is a young woman who "sees".

This series has several books. I recall later in the series the society is struggling and another female character is put into suspended animation and awakened to give guidance when needed.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that is the book!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is The Homecoming Saga by Orson Scott Card. The city of women is called Basilica. Luet is the seer; the woman in suspended animation is Shedemei.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homecoming_Saga

[image]